# How to instantiate a Resource Manager

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, silverlight-4.0, embedded-resource

I want to have a class in a WPF app that can extract strings from a resx generated class without having to know the actual resx. other than by the params needed to  instantitiate the ResourceManager and use GetString()

The test for the project structure shown fails however:

[image]

```
[Test]
public void CanGetString() {
    var expected = MainWindow.MenuItem_Header_English;    // value is "English"
            var baseName = MainWindow.ResourceManager.BaseName;
            var asm = typeof (MainWindow).Assembly;
            var rm = new ResourceManager(baseName, asm);
    var actual = rm.GetString("MenuItem_Header_English"); // returns null
    Assert.That(expected, Is.EqualTo(actual));
}
```

Can someone confirm this should be possible and tell me what I am doing wrong? Is there a better way to read string values embedded resources?

Cheers,
Berryl

Comment: you can't compare String literal to type so what you are wanting is not possible.. now for your test you will have to figure out how to get at the header type and check the names good luck

Answer (score 0):

will this work for you

```
   var rm =  MainWindow.ResourceManager.GetString("MenuItem_Header_English")
   var expected = MainWindow.MenuItem_Header_English;
```

// not sure how you are comparing String value to what looks like a type..